# Return JSON object from JSP to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I am trying to return JSON Object/Array from JSP to JavaScript. I dont know how to import JSP file in JS. I have populated JSON Array with DB values.

**main.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
                $("#search").autocomplete({     
                source : function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                        url : "operation.jsp",
                        type : "GET",
                        data : {
                                term : request.term
                        },
                        dataType : "json",
                        success : function(data) {
                                response(data);
                        }
                });
        }
});
});
```

**Operation.jsp**:

```
               try{
                    Class.forName(driverName);
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userId, password);
                    System.out.println("Connection Success");
                    statement = connection.createStatement();
                    String sql = "SELECT * FROM sample";

                    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("Name"));
                        System.out.println(resultSet.getString("Age"));

                       object.put("Name", resultSet.getString("Name"));
                        object.put("Age", resultSet.getString("Age"));
                        array.put(object);

                    }
                    System.out.println("The Array is" + array);

                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                   response.getWriter().write(array.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I need to populate the return JSON data in HTML Dropdown box.

Comment: What happens when you run that?

Comment: just my html page with dropdown box shows......even alert is also not coming

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console? (F12 to open dev tools in most browsers.)

Comment: no errors in browser console

Comment: Does syso prints the value of `The Array is ..` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your jsp is creating a json Array, but the problem is in sending that data to Ajax call. 
I would like to suggest few things to do:

**1.**  add a writer `flush` & `close` statements in JSP.

```
 response.getWriter().write(array.toString()); 
 response.getWriter().flush(); 
 response.getWriter().close();`
```

**2.** Set contentType of JSP page as below:
   `<%@page contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"%>`

**3.** If JSP is not being called(`syso does not prints anything`) then check the relative path of `url : "operation.jsp"`.
In your web-app, it can be like this `/operation.jsp`
  Make use of servlet instead of JSP, Since you are writing only java code in JSP.
In case of servlet the url will be `url : 'operation'`.
`operation` is the url of servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to changing your JSON keys as follows:

```
object.put("label", resultSet.getString("Name"));
object.put("value", resultSet.getString("Age"));
```

Because, according to [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> The **label** property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The **value** will
>   be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item.